# Specify a pixel in image magick

Tags: imagemagick

Where can I find documentation for this?

I am trying this option:

```
-format "%[pixel: u.p{1,1}]"
```

And it gets the pixel 1,1.

How could I get pixel at 100% of the image, I tried:

```
-format "%[pixel: u.p{100%,100%}]"
-format "%[pixel: u.p{-1,-1}]"
```

I was reading [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php), but this is difficult to understand as pixel entry says:

```
p = pixel to use (absolute or relative to current pixel)
```

## Context

The complete command I am using is:

```
color=`convert ~/Desktop/my_image.png -format "%[pixel: u.p{-1,-1}]" info:`
```

And I am trying to get the color in the last pixel of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the documentation i suggest you try `u.p{w-1,h-1}`